# Getting RSS feeds dynamically once new articles come

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I am planning to integrate RSS of a sports website into my web application.

So is there a way to register a callback to get the new articles as they are updated in the sports website.

I am using PHP on my server. I want to make the process dynamic.

Comment: The best Solution would be a Cronjob with the RSS-fetching Script inside. Then you can store or direct link the News-Entries.

Comment: So that is like a timer, post which a check will be done for new entries?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I run a Website, which checks about 200 RSS-Feeds. The Script is executed every 5 Minutes. It reads all RSS-Feeds which are last read > 30 Minutes and does not read all which are < 30 Minutes to minimize the Executiontime each Time the Cronjob is called. The Project searches for specific News from various Newspapers depending on Keywords.

Comment: That is very nice. I was thinking if there was a callback there would not be a timely check. I did introduce a timer in the basic application but was just wondering if there was a callback way possible. Anyways, Thanks a lot ! :-)